# Why can't I use git without sudo?

Tags: git, ubuntu, sudo

I have installed `git` on my Ubuntu using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install git -y
```

I don't login as the root user. I login as a normal user. But whenever I try to use `git`, I get this error:

```
error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied
```

And if I use `sudo` it is solved.

How can I fix this? I don't want to be forced to always prefix my git commands with sudo.

Also I can't pull my existing repo and I get this error:

```
hostkeys_find_by_key_hostfile: hostkeys_foreach failed for /root/.ssh/known_hosts: Too many levels of symbolic links
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.4)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:*************.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/root/.ssh/known_hosts).
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: you have cloned or created the repo with a different user, just init your repo with your user

Comment: Let me Google that for you: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cannot+open+.git%2FFETCH_HEAD%3A+Permission+denied

Comment: @matt, they are both one questions. They are both related to permission.

Comment: All the more reason to search first.

Comment: nope they are not related, one is file system permission so your local machine, the other is access to the remote server

Comment: @Ôrel how can I know which user is used to clone this repo? Is there a git or linux command for that?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a permission problem. Maybe you did the initial `clone` as root?

You can see the current owner/group by using `ls -l .git`

If you want to change the owner to yourself, use

```
sudo chown -R "$USER" -- /path/to/your/local/repo/folder
```

To see what the command changes, use add `--changes` like this:

```
sudo chown -R --changes "$USER" -- /path/to/your/local/repo/folder
```

After fixing the permissions you should also be able to pull (without sudo)